# Apache camel - split xml file by element size (max element per file)

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want to split xml file.

original file:

```
<home>
   <address>a1</address>
   <address>a2</address>
   <address>a3</address>
   <address>a4</address>
   ....
   ....
   <address>an</address>
</home>
```

For an example, I want to split above xml file with 2 address element in each file.

file1:

```
<home>
   <address>a1</address>
   <address>a2</address>
</home>
```

file2:

```
<home>
   <address>a1</address>
   <address>a2</address>
</home>
```

....

file m:

```
<home>
   <address>a(n-1)</address>
   <address>an</address>
</home>
```

I tried as below. But I cannot get the expected result.

```
from("file:///home/tharanga/task2/input?noop=true&delete=true")
 .split(xpath("home/address"))
 .streaming()
 .aggregate(AggregationStrategies.groupedExchange())
 .constant(true)
 .completionSize(2)
 .completionTimeout(1000)
 .to("file:///home/tharanga/task2/output2");
```

Greatly appreciate your help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`groupedExcange` aggregation strategy will combine the exchanges into a list, so you have to implement an additional processing for them. To make it simpler I would suggest you to add `.convertBodyTo(String.class)` and also use `GroupedBodyAggregationStrategy` instead of `GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy` to get a `List<String>` as a result of aggregation.

Assuming this your processor would look like

```
.process(new Processor()) {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
         String body = exchange.getIn().getBody().join();
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         sb.append("<home>");
         sb.append(body);
         sb.append("</home>");
         exchange.getIn().setBody(sb.toString());
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the proper solution for the above task.

We can use the **xtokanize** and refer below link for more details.

https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/split-eip.html#_streaming_big_xml_payloads_using_tokenizer_language

Find the below code sample for my task:

```
from("file:///home/tharanga/task2/input?noop=true&delete=true")
    .split()
    .xtokenize("//home/address", 'w', new Namespaces(), 2)
    .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, simple("${file:name.noext}-${header.CamelSplitIndex}.${file:ext}"))
    .to("file:///home/tharanga/task2/output8?noop=true");
```